# How to I access the DbContext of EF core from another project when used in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I followed the pattern to use EF Core with ASP.NET core and all is well. But recently I created a 'Calculation' project and want to make database calls from it.

The problem is I don't know how to create a new `DbContextOptions`. In my code that is done with

```
   services.AddDbContext<RetContext>(options => options
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

But in a new .NET core class I need to provide it manually. How do I do this ? My code is like this:

```
 public static class LoadData
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public static RefProgramProfileData Load_RefProgramProfileData(string code)
    {
        // var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RetContext>();
        // optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        //How do I make an optionsbuilder and get the configuration from the WEB project?
       UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new RetContext(optionsBuilder));


        var loadedRefProgramProfileData  = uow.RefProgramProfileDataRepository
            .Find(x => x.ProgramCode == code).FirstOrDefault();

        return loadedRefProgramProfileData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you add a reference to your database project from your calculation project, or better still make them part of the same parent project

Comment: I did. But Not to the web project since that would not make sense. I just need to be able to use the DbContext like my web project does. In the web project it has the startup and the DI. I can't figure out how to simply get a context the normal way

Comment: you should use dependency injection in all projects and avoid use of static classes and methods except for extension methods

Comment: I could use DI in the same way as the web but do not know how to set up DI in a non web project. It seems its set up in BuildWebHost and I don't want that ..but yes.. it is something I can look into .. worse case I put the helper in my web project but that doesn't make sense

Comment: Put your DbContext into it's own project so it can be referenced by both your web and non-web projects.

Comment: Yes it is in its own project but the way ASP.NET core accesses it is with the WebBuilderHost and not just newing it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may instantiate your `DbContext` like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var configuration = builder.Build();
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RetContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnection("DefaultConnection"));
_context = new RetContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

---

However, the ideal is to use dependency injection. Let's say you have a class `CalculationService` in your other project. For that, you need to register that class as a service that can be injected:

```
services.AddScoped<CalculationService>();
```

Then your class can receive `DbContext` (or any other services) through DI:

```
public class CalculationService
{
    private RetContext _context;

    public CalculationService(RetContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Naturally, you won't be able to instantiate your class manually like this:

```
var service = new CalculationService();
```

Instead, you'd need to make whatever class needs to use your `CalculationService` to also receive it through DI and make that class injectable as well.

Comment: And needed :  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();

             var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RetContext>();
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

Comment: @punkouter I added that to the code sample, thank you!