# Get Dbcontext dynamically ef

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core project that provides NuGet packages for other sub-projects.
I Want to write a method that gets active DBcontexts in the project.

**Whats Situation:**

> For example, I Create Method **A** in the main project.
>
> I generate the
> NuGet package and all the subprojects can now use method **A** but in
> each project, we have different conditions and situations so they must
> be Generic.I'm in a situation that I Want to access to Dbcontexts
> dynamically.

All the projects have the same structure and they use Dependency injection so is there any way to access Ioc or injects and get Dbcontexts or any better way is available?

Comment: This looks like something you need: [access the DbContext of EF core from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805184/how-to-i-access-the-dbcontext-of-ef-core-from-another-project-when-used-in-asp-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution
By injecting **IServiceCollection** you can have access to all of the collection of service descriptors.

```
public class CoreClass
{
 protected IServiceCollection _serviceDescriptors;

 public CoreClass(IServiceCollection serviceDescriptors)
 {
        _serviceDescriptors = serviceDescriptors;
 }

   private List<DbContext> GetContexts()
  {
        List<DbContext> listdb = new List<DbContext>();
        foreach (ServiceDescriptor sd in _serviceDescriptors
            .Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbContext))))
        {
            listdb.Add((DbContext)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(sd.ServiceType));
        }
        return listdb;
    }
}
```